# Unity injection of an instance inside WebAPI action

Tags: unity-container

I am stuck with this and I wonder what is the best way to approach this problem. I have a WebApi controller where I want to inject ICommand instance but I can know what is the instance I need once I inspect the Post request data. I'll give an example to be more clear but my question also applies to Winform events where you receive an event argument and depending of this event arg you want to have different implementation injected.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public object Post(int id)
    {
        ICommand command = null;

        if(id = 1)
        {
            command = new Id1Command();
        }
        else
        {
            command = new Id2Command();
        }

        return new object();
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is creating a factory that accepts unity container as argument and inside that factory to call container.Resolve with named instance.

My problem with that is that I am taught that you shouldn't register or resolve outside your composition root and that is violation of the good practices (according Mark Seemann). I am looking for the best design for this problem in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CommandFactory and pass it to the TestController:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICommandFactory mCommandFactory;

    public TestController(ICommandFactory CommandFactory)
    {
        mCommandFactory = CommandFactory;
    }

    public object Post(int id)
    {
        ICommand command = null;

        if(id = 1)
        {
            command = CommandFactory.CreateId1Command();
        }
        else
        {
            command = CommandFactory.CreateId2Command();
        }

        return new object();
    }
}
```

Now you have to make sure that Unity is creating the TestController. To do so, you have to implement, configure and set an IDependencyResolver. Check [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

**Edit to your comment:**

For this scenario you can use an autofactory using a functor that takes an int:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly Func<int, ICommand> mCommandFactory

    public TestController(Func<int, ICommand> CommandFactory)
    {
        mCommandFactory = CommandFactory;
    }

    public object Post(int id)
    {
        var command mCommandFactory(id);

        return new object();
    }
}
```

The registration should look like this:

```
container.RegisterType<Func<int, ICommand>>(new InjectionFactory(
    c => new Func<int, ICommand>(
                id =>
                {
                    if (id == 1)
                    {
                        return new Command();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new Command2();
                    }
                })));
```

Note: You still have to set the DependencyResolver!

Comment: So I'll move creation of the command instance in the factory but I think that is not good enough, because I still have to use "new Id1Command" inside the factory and the instance won't be managed by the container. I am looking for something like container.Resolve<Icommand>(id) but I don't want to use container.Resolve inside the factory, because I think using it outside of composition root is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found also this which is the most elegant way of addressing this but unfortunately you need 3rd party extension for it https://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/auto-generated-factories-with-unity/

Comment: Also, if you don't want to "new up" Command objects you could also have the container inject Func<Command> factories as in the [Auto Factories example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec32) and have the factory invoke the appropriate Func<>.